# Duplicate Rows extracted into VIEW

Tags: sql, distinct

I have got this code to create a View for me, but it duplicates every line, despite the DISTINCT command, any ideas?

```
Use [Table] 
Go  
CREATE VIEW View_Database_1Mth_Composite AS 
SELECT DISTINCT Composite.[DealerCode]  
  ,DealerDetails.[BrandTradeName]
  ,DealerDetails.[GroupName]
  ,DealerDetails.[Brand]
  ,DealerDetails.[RBM]
  ,Composite.[Ratio_ID] 
  ,CAST (RatioID.[Detail_Desc] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS Detail_Desc 
  ,Composite.[LineNr]   
  ,Composite.[201301]   
  ,Composite.[201302]   
  ,Composite.[201303]   
  ,Composite.[201304]   
  ,Composite.[201305]   
  ,Composite.[201306]   
  ,Composite.[201307]   
  ,Composite.[201308]   
  ,Composite.[201309]   
  ,Composite.[201310]   
FROM [Company_Database].[dbo].[Database_1Mth_Composite$] as Composite   
INNER JOIN [Company_Database].[dbo].[Company_DealerDetails] as DealerDetails    
ON CAST(Composite.[DealerCode] AS VARCHAR(10))=DealerDetails.[DlrCode]  
-- 2nd Join for the Ratio_ID    
INNER JOIN [Company_Database].[dbo].[Database_RatioID] as RatioID   
ON Composite.[Ratio_ID]=RatioID.[Ratio] 
[Company_Database].[dbo].[Database_RatioID] as RatioID
```

I have tried reversing the order of the 1st join, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding: `GROUP BY Composite.[DealerCode]  
  ,DealerDetails.[BrandTradeName]
  ,DealerDetails.[GroupName]
  ,DealerDetails.[Brand]
  ,DealerDetails.[RBM]
  ,Composite.[Ratio_ID] 
  ,CAST (RatioID.[Detail_Desc] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS Detail_Desc 
  ,Composite.[LineNr]   
  ,Composite.[201301]   
  ,Composite.[201302]   
  ,Composite.[201303]   
  ,Composite.[201304]   
  ,Composite.[201305]   
  ,Composite.[201306]   
  ,Composite.[201307]   
  ,Composite.[201308]   
  ,Composite.[201309]   
  ,Composite.[201310]  `  to the end of your query.

Comment: if it has duplicated lines some thing is different from one line to other. I'm betting on `CAST (RatioID.[Detail_Desc] AS VARCHAR(8000)) `

Comment: Can you show some data example?

Comment: @JorgeCampos The Cast does seem to be the issue, whem I use Oscar suggestion, I pick up an issue. Do you want to see the data going into the Joins? Where can I leave it for you?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure View, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. It is the AS in the Group By Statement in the Cast (RatioID.   line

Comment: Ok, I see... change it for `GROUP BY  Composite.[DealerCode] ,DealerDetails.[BrandTradeName] ,DealerDetails.[GroupName] ,DealerDetails.[Brand] ,DealerDetails.[RBM] ,Composite.[Ratio_ID] ,CAST (RatioID.[Detail_Desc] AS VARCHAR(8000)) ,Composite.[LineNr] ,Composite.[201301] ,Composite.[201302] ,Composite.[201303] ,Composite.[201304] ,Composite.[201305] ,Composite.[201306] ,Composite.[201307] ,Composite.[201308] ,Composite.[201309] ,Composite.[201310]`

Comment: Hi Oscar, it does run out fine, BUT the duplication is still there. I do drop and recreate the view every time.

Comment: @Herman use the http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Then, as @JorgeCampos says, it must be that there's something different. Coud you post two "EQUAL" lines for us to see them?

Comment: The line has got several more fields, and on closer inspection, I saw that the Detail_Desc field has 2 different descriptions, which is flaw in the D/B.
My apologies, but thanks a lot for the assistance!

Comment: Just a little advise: in general, specially on a ORACLE Database, using a `GROUP BY` clause is more efficient than using a `DISTINCT` operator.

Comment: Will keep that in mind, thanks! Any help with these massive D/B's will do!

Answer (score 0):

A single field was different, which caused this problem.

Thanks to all for your help, I might have spent too much time looking for a solution, and didnt see the problem!